# AWS: cloudformation CommaDelimitedList and manual list not matching

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create a cloudformation template that has default values, and I'm running a few `!Sub` functions to replace imported parameters into the template.
However, I am passing a list to a nodejs Lambda function that I need to `!Sub` before sending it.

The code that I'm writing:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Description: Creating Athena database and tables

Parameters:
  S3DataLocations:
    Type: CommaDelimitedList
    Description: The S3 locations where the logs are read from (Specify 'Use,Default' to inherit defaults)
    Default: Use,Default

Conditions:
  CustomS3DataLocations: !Equals ['Use,Default', !Join [",", !Ref S3DataLocations]]

Resources:
  # Custom resource for running CreateTableFunction, to create databases
  CreateLogTable:
    Type: Custom::CreateLogTable
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt [CreateLogTableFunction, Arn]
      S3DataLocations:
        Fn::If:
          - CustomS3DataLocations
          - !Split
            - ","
            - !Sub
              - s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs1/,
                s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs2/,
                s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs3/
              - { LoggingBucket: !ImportValue Parent-LoggingBucket}
          - !Ref S3DataLocations
```

If I pass these as a literal external `DataTypes` parameter `s3://logbucket/data/ApplicationLogs1/,s3://logbucket/data/ApplicationLogs2/,s3://logbucket/data/ApplicationLogs3/` it works fine and translates to `["s3://logbucket/data/ApplicationLogs1/","s3://logbucket/data/ApplicationLogs2/","s3://logbucket/data/ApplicationLogs3/"]` and is interpreted by the Lambda without issue.
The parameter gets parsed through the `CommaDelimitedList` type and is passed to the Lambda without issue.

The issue arises in that I am trying to create a manual default, so I need to `!Sub` a list, as a string, then `!Split` to be passed as an actual list to the Custom Lambda. This doesn't seem to be working every way I try it and I cannot figure why.

I've been inspecting the success (manual param) and failure (defaults, without manual param) and I cant see a big difference.
The event of the lambda shows, when working:

```
{
    "RequestType": "Create",
    "ServiceToken": "hidden",
    "ResponseURL": "hidden",
    "StackId": "hidden",
    "RequestId": "hidden",
    "LogicalResourceId": "CreateLogTable",
    "ResourceType": "Custom::CreateLogTable",
    "ResourceProperties": {
        "S3DataLocations": [
            "s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/",
            "s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/",
            "s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/",
            "s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/"
        ]
    }
}
```

And when NOT working:

```
...
{
    "RequestType": "Create",
    "ServiceToken": "hidden",
    "ResponseURL": "hidden",
    "StackId": "hidden",
    "RequestId": "hidden",
    "LogicalResourceId": "CreateLogTable",
    "ResourceType": "Custom::CreateLogTable",
    "ResourceProperties": {
        "S3DataLocations": [
            "s3://logging/data/ApplicationLogs/",
            " s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/",
            " s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/",
            " s3://loggingbucket/data/ApplicationLogs/"
        ]
    }
}
```

I'm a little stuck here, I think there might be some Type mismatch but I cant tell the difference between the manual and param.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: Do you have put your ` s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs1/,` in different lines? The end-of-lines are changed into spaces, thus you get this extra space at the front of your strings in your lambda.

Comment: Ideally, I'd like to find a way to not have them all on the same line, for readability. The sample is shorter, but there are actually about a dozen S3 URLs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can break your string into multiple line while preventing the change of `\n` into space using **quotation and slash** combo.

To verify that, I used the following surrogate template for your situation:

```
Resources:

  MyBucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket
    Properties: {}

Outputs:
  Test1:
    Value: !Sub
          - s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs1/,
            s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs2/,
            s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs3/
          - { LoggingBucket: "Parent-LoggingBucket"}

  Test2:
    Value: !Sub
          - "s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs1/,\
            s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs2/,\
            s3://${LoggingBucket}/data/ApplicationLogs3/"
          - { LoggingBucket: "Parent-LoggingBucket"}
```

The `Test1` produces string with spaces as in your question:

```
s3://Parent-LoggingBucket/data/ApplicationLogs1/, s3://Parent-LoggingBucket/data/ApplicationLogs2/, s3://Parent-LoggingBucket/data/ApplicationLogs3/
```

In contrast, `Test2` does not have space:

```
s3://Parent-LoggingBucket/data/ApplicationLogs1/,s3://Parent-LoggingBucket/data/ApplicationLogs2/,s3://Parent-LoggingBucket/data/ApplicationLogs3/
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I still get spaces when I use the `Test2` method. I've been trying a few different approaches to stringify the list and it always seems to output the same result (With spaces). Maybe it has something to do with the `!Split` function below it, but I keep experimenting.

Comment: Hi @Marcin, further to testing further and going back over your answer, it looks like when using your `Test2` example I left out the `\\` at the end of each line. Adding the slash line breaks fixed the issue. Thanks!